# selecting the least value in a joined table

Tags: mysql

Basically I have `product` and several `model`s for those `product`s. Each `model` has a `price`.

This is what I intended to do:

Mark a `product` as *featured*, then have it's `title`, `description`, number 1 image's `thumbnail` and the `price` for the cheapest `model`

This is my current query:

```
SELECT
  product.title,
  product.url_name,
  product.description,
  price.price,
  image.thumbnail
FROM
  mps_contents AS product
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
    mps_contents AS image 
    ON
      image.page_id = product.content_id AND
      image.display_order = '1' AND
      image.resource_type = 'image'
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
    mps_contents AS model 
    ON
      product.content_id = model.page_id
  INNER JOIN
    mps_product_info AS price
    ON
      model.content_id = price.content_id
WHERE
  product.active = '1' AND
  product.resource_type = 'product' AND
  product.featured = '1'
ORDER BY RAND( )
LIMIT 3
```

You may see that my query cannot do the `price` sorting, I hope somebody could help me with that. An additional problem that I encounter is if I have multiple `model`s for a `product`. I end up getting a set that has `price`s for 2 `model`s from a single `product` when the intent is to have the 1 `price` for each `product`.

I am aware of the issue with `ORDER BY RAND()` but I will ignore it since I don't think this site will have more that 50 products.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think something like this should work....

```
SELECT
  product.title,
  product.url_name,
  product.description,
  A.price,
  image.thumbnail
FROM
  mps_contents AS product
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
    mps_contents AS image 
    ON
      image.page_id = product.content_id AND
      image.display_order = '1' AND
      image.resource_type = 'image'
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (
      SELECT price.price 
      FROM mps_contents AS model 
      JOIN mps_product_info price ON (model.content_id = price.content_id) 
      WHERE model.page_id = product.content_id 
      ORDER BY price.price
      LIMIT 1
  ) AS A
WHERE
  product.active = '1' AND
  product.resource_type = 'product' AND
  product.featured = '1'
ORDER BY RAND( )
LIMIT 3
```

Comment: Syntax error found before the `WHERE` of the main query. Maybe because `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s aren't supposed to be aliased that way? I've modified the query by moving the subquery to the SELECT clause. Thanks for the idea on the subquery!